# How to catch the jQuery.event.trigger()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to build a custom event with jQuery that is not set to a DOM element.

It says in the jQuery description, that:

```
jQuery.event.trigger('test');
```

is to trigger an Custom Event.

But how i can catch it ??

thx in advance

Comment: You mean catching of `trigger`, or of that custom event?

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/6bWJ6/

Comment: i mean that custom event (sorry if I expressed myself wrong) ..

Comment: yes, but without a DOM element in selector ..

Comment: Where did you see `jQuery.event.trigger('test')`?

Comment: in jQuery source code you can find `jQuery.event.trigger`. To listen to these events you can probably use `$( document ).on('test', callback)`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I suppose you're asking about that custom event (at least it made no sense for me attempting to catch the `trigger`): it's done with [.bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/):

```
$('some_selector').bind('test', function() { 
  console.log('Test was caught'); }
);
```

**UPDATE:** Actually no, you don't need a selector - just an object to be a 'host' of event. You might use something like this:

```
// taken from the comments at the Doc page
var o = {length: 3};
$(o).bind( 'custom', function(){ console.log('hi') } );
$(o).trigger('custom');

// Output
hi
hi
hi
```

Comment: What is the length attribute?

Comment: You don't need a selector but an object at least. And it needs the `length` property, **I guess**, because of [some checks jQuery does in that object](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/1905-jquery-event-bindings-on-javascript-objects-with-a-length-property.htm). I couldn't find the example in the `Doc page` mentioned in the code comment.

Comment: Also there is a ⚠️warning in the [trigger() documentation page](https://api.jquery.com/trigger/), referring to the `length` property, but it's unclear to me what it exactly means.

Answer (score 9):

I think you guys are missing the question.  He is not asking how you listen for an event triggered on an object.  He is asking how you listen for an event triggered directly through jQuery.event.trigger().

I found a really great article at http://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-custom-events/.

Essentially you just listen on the document object.

```
$(document).on("test", function(event, data) {
  console.log(data)
});

$.event.trigger('test', [{ foo: 'bar' }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

you should pass the target element of the event to jQuery.event.trigger(), like this:

```
jQuery.event.trigger('test', null, element);
```

so that when you want to catch it, you can use :

```
$(element).on('test', fn);
```

You can find the definition and usage of jQuery.event.trigger in the jQuery source:

After reading source code of jQuery, you'd find the definition of jQuery.event.trigger:

```
jQuery.event = {
    ...

    trigger: function( event, data, elem, onlyHandlers ) {...}

    ...
}
```

(this is not meant to be a public interface of jQuery and just for internal use.)

and the usage:

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
...
    trigger: function( type, data ) {
        return this.each(function() {
            jQuery.event.trigger( type, data, this );
        });
    },
    triggerHandler: function( type, data ) {
        var elem = this[0];
        if ( elem ) {
            return jQuery.event.trigger( type, data, elem, true );
        }
    },
...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how:

```
$(document).bind('test', function (e) {
  // handler code here...
});
```