# How to use bind and event on global objct

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to bind an event to a global object.
Using the following code I receive an error in jquery js file

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined

```
  // bind input events
    $(window.APP).bind('keyDown', function() {
        console.log('test')
    });


    keyDown: function(keycode) {
        $(window.APP).trigger()('keyDown', keycode);
    },
```

using jQuery JavaScript Library v1.4.2

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: what is 'window.APP' ? Events are for DOM objects btw. And this code use wrong syntax: `$(window.APP).trigger()('keyDown', keycode)`

Comment: window.APP it is not a DOM object in my case. Can I attach event to a not DOM obect?

Comment: So, how could you bind event to a not DOM object, doesn't make sense at all

Comment: I was looking at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11132553/how-to-catch-the-jquery-event-trigger

Comment: Seems strange behaviour and i don't see any purpose of this because you still need to trigger event manually. So why not just call a function of object?

Answer (score 1):

This line seems wrong:

```
$(window.APP).trigger()('keyDown', keycode);
```

It should be:

```
$(window.APP).trigger('keyDown', keycode);
```